# Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1

Tags: android

While generating APK, It's showing build failed, this is the error message :

```
    Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Abde/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Help me ! 
thank you

Comment: Post your project-level `build.gradle` file

Comment: I found its solution. Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585245/3675182)

Answer (score 28):

If you're running lint on a project that you created using an older version of Android Studio, you may encounter this error.

Your top-level project **build.gradle** ought to have the `google()` repository in order to fetch this dependency like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // The order in which you list these repositories matter.
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Note that: The `google()` repo is a **shortcut** to looks in Google's Maven repository for dependencies. It was introduced with [Gradle v.4.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google()) (required Android Studio 3.x and Gradle plugin 3.x).

In any case (Android Studio 2.x, gradle plugin 2.x.x, or gradle v3.x) you can use the same maven repo using `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`. It is the same.

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem but i do have the google() repo. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I had google() already in my repositories section. Doing @SachinTyagi recommendation works for me. His recommendation is to add the following to the repository section: maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

Comment: The only solution that worked for me was to go to Build --> Build Types, and add google() to both repos

Comment: What worked for me was to move the `google()` entry above the `jcenter()` one, i.e, change the order of the entries.

Comment: if you already have google() repo but still having this error check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016468/4565796

Answer (score 6):

make sure the google() repo for repositories is in both your buildscript and allprojects sections.

Answer (score -1):

For those who experience the same problem, try adding this to App Builde.gradle :

```
android {
    //the rest of the code above

    lintOptions {
       disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```

I had the same problem, and this, for whatever reason, worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

First Generate : cacerts file

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore {your-home-directory}\.AndroidStudio3.0\system\tasks\cacerts -destkeystore .\cacerts -v
```

then add this code in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\ProgramFiles\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_171\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts

systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```