# react native - error while fetching build tools files

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am unable to build my android app using `react-native run-android`, because I get following error. Yesterday everything worked fine. Do you know where could be the problem?

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'contacto'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.1.2/manifest-merger-26.1.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.1.2/builder-test-api-3.1.2.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.1.0/aapt2-proto-0.1.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.1.2/builder-model-3.1.2.jar
   > Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/26.1.2/annotations-26.1.2.jar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563338/could-not-find-runtime-jar-android-arch-lifecycleruntime1-0-0)

Comment: Yeah, seems like a problem with repository (server side) as stated in the duplicate question

Comment: Yup, the first answer on that post is correct for this error.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line in your project`s gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .....
        ......
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }  //  Add this line.
        ......
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to go to Build --> Build Types, and add **google()** to both repos

Answer (score -2):

For those who have the same error, try adding this to App Builde.gradle :

```
android {
    //the rest of the code above

    lintOptions {
       disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```

I had the same problem, and this, for whatever reason, worked for me.