# Cannot successfully rebuild android project - conflict in snapshot release handling policy

Tags: android

We get below message every time we **rebuild** the project in android studio, any idea how to resolve this issue?

> The repository 'oss-snapshot-local' rejected the resolution of an
>   artifact
>   'oss-snapshot-local:com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom'
>   due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy.

We tried deleting the local build folder and every time we click on REBUILD project we get the error again, but no error when clicking the RUN button in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

We found out that our office wifi is blocking the download so we were able to resolve issue by:

1. Unblocking download from repository
2. In build.gradle add google() repository in both **allprojects** and **buildscript** as suggested from here : [Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085237/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle26-1-1/50347126)