# I can't Export Apk File In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Ali/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.jar
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.3/lint-gradle-26.1.3.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972122/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle-android-studio-3)

Comment: You need to say something more about what you are trying to do and how you configured the app

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following in your project build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing the google() repository in order to fetch the dependency.

Here's the link to the pom file that you're looking for: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/testutils/26.1.0-alpha01/testutils-26.1.0-alpha01.pom

source :https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127602/10153377