# Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation

Tags: ubuntu, gradle, kotlin, gradlew

When running `./gradlew clean build` I get following message:

```
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

I have JDK, `JAVA_HOME` is set properly, so is `update-alternatives`.

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.16.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

```
# update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java               1100      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java               1100      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Here's gradle build with stacktrace enabled:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:255)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 111 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:92)
        ... 124 more
```

So from what I can see, it's failing during search for `tools.jar` - which I have under `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib`, since the configured path is to JDK.

My `gradle.build` - just in case:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
}

ext {
    ktorVersion = "1.1.2"
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktorVersion"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktorVersion"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktorVersion"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktorVersion"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.22'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-ktor:2.0.0-beta-3'
    implementation 'org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:3.10.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

I'm truly at a loss, would appreciate some help.

If any more information is needed let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix it? Because I am fighting it for two days already and can't figure out what's the matter.

Comment: The solution is in the error message! "Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE." JAVA_HOME must point to a JDK path and the message says yours is pointing to a JRE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63576967/12534

Answer (score 140):

I solved a similar problem in MacOS (Big Sur). In my case I was running a React Native project and got the following error when trying to build to Android:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bugsnag_react-native:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by G
radle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

I followed [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-577CEA7C-E51C-416D-B9C6-B1469F45AC78) for uninstalling the JRE on MacOS. Slightly modified to make the process reversible, here are the steps:

```
cd /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
mv JavaAppletPlugin.plugin DELETED-JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
cd /Library/PreferencePanes/
mv JavaControlPanel.prefPane DELETED-JavaControlPanel.prefPane
```

When you receive `Permission denied` use `sudo` before commands.

I then cleared my Gradle folder. I don't know if this is necessary, but it worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle
```

Finally, I rebuilt my project (`react-native run-android`) and everything worked.

I'm not sure removing the JRE is the best solution since you may need the JRE for other things, but I have not noticed any ill effects. Also, it appears I already had a JDK installed which may not be true for all Mac users.

Since there are not any good answers on Stack Overflow that address this problem on MacOS, I figured I'd post my solution here.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue after updating to Big Sur. This saved me a ton of frustration.

Comment: Uninstalling all java https://osxdaily.com/2017/06/16/uninstall-java-mac/ and install again helped me to solve this problem after ugrade MacOS on Big Sure

Comment: This worked for me and as mentioned in MacOS Big Sur. I also omitted clearing the gradle folder. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks you saved me ... every time Apple does a major update some JDK/gradle/... stuff breaks

Comment: With all these steps I also had to install latest jdk https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html and everything worked.

Comment: "rm -rf ~/.gradle" was no necessary to do for me, I'm working on android studio and native code, I just upgraded to Big Sur and I faced this issue

Comment: Thanks dude, you've saved a lot of time to me. I upgrade to Mac Os Big Sur and same problem. Your fix has worked for me

Comment: In my case in MacOS after update to BigSur I had to update my JAVA_HOME path in the command line `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Just updated to BigSure, same issue in Android Studio. I've followed the suggestion and renamed the `JavaAppletPlugin` and the `JavaControlPanel`, also I've set the JAVA_HOME path as suggested in the previous comment. Everything went fine, didn't have to remove the `.gradle` folder, after checking that the compilation works again I removed completely the previous plugins. Thank you!

Comment: you saved me from insane frustation. thank you man

Comment: Thank you *20, I went so far as to log in to actually upvote you for the concise response. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked with flutter issue as well. The error message is "Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE. flutter"

Answer (score 61):

android studio also offers jdk.
If you specify that jdk as below, it will succeed

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no need to install another JVM

Comment: This was working for me but now i get an error saying invalid path after an android studio update. I needed to change the second line to `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`

Comment: this worked for me, if someone sure that he has java so that is the correct answer

Comment: This is definitely the answer for Mac with @James update

Comment: This solution helps me on MAC.

Thank you

Answer (score 41):

Following MacOS update to Big Sur, I was seeing the same problem as Tom Aranda above.
Upon further investigation, I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917779/wrong-java-home-after-upgrade-to-macos-big-sur-v11-0-1) and this led me to [this radar](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666681). I wasn't happy removing the JRE as per Tom's answer and so have worked around my own install with details from the other posts.....

My previous declaration of `JAVA_HOME` was in `~/.zshrc` as

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

but Big Sur appears to have updated the default JRE version to 1.8 also. So my JAVA_HOME needs to be more precise with its filtering.

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.251.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_241 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

And I now export as

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_241`
```

Now this isn't ideal as it'll break the next time I update the JDK.

As per the details in the radar and the other SO post I also need to ensure that any existing exported JAVA_HOME is unset before exporting again, so my new entry in `~/.zshrc`has now become

```
unset JAVA_HOME;export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_241`
```

Upon terminal relaunch, my previously failing `gradlew` commands now function as before.

To me this feels like a better solution as I've not removed any libs and I have only affected java home from my own terminal commands. It's a shame that I need to specify the precise version as this will break at some point in the future.

Answer (score 17):

on BIG SUR people who get this error have probably got a custom java installation. Remove it with the following

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencesPanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

after that unset any custom JAVA_HOME you have and remove it from your shell and it should start working again.

Comment: This worked for me. I also downloaded and installed the JDK I needed from Oracle. My commands were still broken until I ran the above as well.

Comment: Thanks, man!
It does the trick for me as well!

Comment: For me too :P 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the custom installation and set Java home to use the java 8 from Big Sur.

Answer (score 11):

On windows, add this to gradle.properties, with your jdk version

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_102
```

Comment: This is specific to Windows and a certain Java version

Comment: thanks. I do not remember the java version I was using. But this solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...It's working like a charm, you saved my day

Answer (score 10):

I got the exact same problem. I solved it by installing `OpenJDK 8 JDK`. My machine is running `centos` so here is my installing command

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.

I learned from this [article](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-centos-7/) that there are two different Java packages, Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and Java Development Kit (JDK). JRE is for running Java programs, and JDK is for developing Java applications. I only had had JRE installed, but not JDK. After installing JDK, my build ran successfully

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, yum is the package manager for Cent OS.

Answer (score 9):

```
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

it's set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre`.

Should set the JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`

If your OS is Ubuntu, make suer to install openjdk jdk by `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`
will install jre, not jdk

Comment: Also it might help to uninstall the jre version before install the jdk version, because  they shared the same parent path, and I tried to install jdk without removing jre, which didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

From the data provided, It is sure that `java` is in the environment path. But, It doesn't confirm that JAVA_HOME is set to a JDK directory. Are you sure `JAVA_HOME` is not set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre` instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`or `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`?

Because, If `JAVA_HOME` is set, then gradlew will ignore `java` binary in the PATH and execute `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` which in turn will be available in `System.getProperty("java.home")` which is logged in this exception ( see [jarSearchingUtil.Kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/tasks/jarSearchingUtil.kt#L107) )

Otherwise, You can try declaring JAVA_HOME directly in the **gradlew** file

Answer (score 6):

### 1.Install Java

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
[image]

### 2. find java path

/usr/libexec/java_home -V

[image]

### 3. set mac envirment

vim ~/.bash_profile

edit profile:

```java
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home
export CLASSPAHT=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:
```

source ~/.bash_profile

### 4. verify

```java
@B-X24EQ05P-1937 jdk1.8.0_321.jdk % java -version         
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I had to download & install correct Java SDK from official website, it resolves my problem

Answer (score 5):

Things were all working fine before update to Mac Big Sur, I was using Jenkins on my local machine with Fastlane 'sh Fastlane beta' for firebase distribution. It was a flutter project.

I just added `org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` in gradle.properties. And this fixed my issue.

Comment: If this doesn't work then provide absolute path of installed java: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by deleting a kind of version of java.

I had 2 kinds of Java, as below picture.
[image: kinds of Java]

But I got a failure when I was executing `./gradlew clean assembleRelease`, it's remind me maybe the problem is about which JDK I used.
[image: failure]

Then, I find the content of 2 kinds of java's home were different with each other. The left is which one I download from Oracle.

[image: JAVA_HOME content diff]

So, I tried to fix it by deleting the first java's home.(**Compress the folder for copy at first**).

It's work!

Answer (score 2):

**first**

follow @Tom Aranda solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65132651/1367344
**but didn't remove `./gradle` folder**

**second**

if gradle faild :

`./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies` to force Gradle to update dependencies

found this comment in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438866/1367344

Answer (score 1):

Was facing this issue in open jdk 8, switching to open jdk 11 solved it for me.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac, the trick is to install the JDK from Oracle, they are now changing license policies so apparently it isn't totally free anymore for commercial use.
That said, once you install, you find the JDK on the MAC at : "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home"
if you go to gradle.properties, you can insert the line :
"org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home"
into the file.
Restart Android studio, select the Android device, and it should work.
Interestingly enough if you go to Finder, and navigate to the folder, then drag the folder into the gradle.properties file in textedit or vim, the path just shows up magically. I've been using Macs for over 10 years and only found that during this new endeavor into Android Studio.
It did for me. Thanks to Stack Overflow community, it is a essential part of any application developer's toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled alot with this. (MAC OS Monterey)

But what works for me now is

1. Installing the JDK 8 from Oracle's website. (Login was required)
2. Add `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home` in the gradle.properties (jdk1.8.0_331.jdk was the name of my jdk folder, if you have another version you will have to use your own version / folder name there.)
3. I created a file called local.properties in the root of android folder in your project. There i added the line `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk` USERNAME should be your mac's username.

I tried declaring it as a home variable in the terminal but for some reason it wouldn't work. But telling the gradle.properties in step 2 worked it out :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using the system-wide installed tool `gradle` instead of the project tool `./gradlew` works. That is, I run `gradle ...` instead of `./gradlew ...`. If `gradle` is installed on your machine, it should be configured correctly and know where Java is.

Note, I am on macOS, not sure about Linux and Windows, but I imagine should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It was giving me error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE

I solved it by downloading and install Java SE Development Kit 8
and after installed folder has been created in path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my lab has windows 7 and visual studio and android studio and flutter environment.
When i Ran start debugging, same problem was happened.

To solve this problem,

First, Install Java Extension Pack by use extensions on visual studio.

Second, Follow Java Extension Pack, it required JDK 11 on config running screen.

Third, Download and install JDK(java develop kit) 11

Forth, When you install, you have to do check Path set on installation process. Maybe, it is not set Path automatically. you must check making path.

If you set and install correctly, It is appeared automatically at System environment variable as JAVA_HOME name. not user variable.

Run again main dart. you can see emulator correctly

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 20.04, This works for me:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, i have only JRE (Java Runtime Environment) on my machine. Setting

```
JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

works for me

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the same issue setting env variables JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME.

Windows:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15
- C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333

Answer (score -2):

A simple restart on my computer and it worked again