# Getting error "Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation"

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Value 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk15.0.1' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286542/kotlin-could-not-find-the-required-jdk-tools-in-the-java-installation)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions , i have seen it and done accordingly still couldnot resolve it thats why i have posted this

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain why you think your question is a different situation?

Comment: actually i copy pasted the error given, probably because of the latest update in flutter. it has happen many times , i used to solve myself, but this time i couldnt so posted it here

Comment: What have you done to solve it yourself previously?

Comment: i created java_home and added it to the path

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the environment setting is the JDK path is Ok or Not.
if not then add the JDK path in JAVAHOME.
and I think you don't need to add this('C:\Program Files\Java\jdk15.0.1' ) path on Gradle.
if the path variable is ok then it automatically knows the JDK.

thanks.

Comment: I checked the environment variable , everything is properly setup but still showing the error, please help me out