# This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, gradle

> This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or
> Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version
> 4.3 or newer.

The Gradle version is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha05'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I can open these projects with Android Studio canary latest (updated 25th Jan) which IDE version did you use?
Also, once they are open, the android part of the gradle config is not recognized for me.

Comment: And my problem was due to an older version of gradle.

So
`Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 5
Build #AI-203.6682.168.2031.7101492, built on January 25, 2021`
works. Which version do you have?

Comment: I used Android Studio 4.2 beta 2.

Comment: You could install Android Studio Canary (5) and give it try...
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 canary 10. I downgraded the  Gradle to `7.0.0-alpha10` and it worked well.

Comment: But now awaiting for   future dependencies conflicts

Answer (score 4):

Check your Android Studio Version (Help->About) e.g. 4.1.2

Update build.gradle class path to your version:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'`

where 4.1.2 is the version found under Help->About

Alternatively, you could just update your Android Studio Version to what is suggested.

Comment: this simple solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains's support gave the similar answer as [wandesky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738543/1455694):

> The message means that the Android plugin bundled with 2021.2 version
> is not compatible with the Android Gradle plugin used by your Gradle
> project:
>
> com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0
>
> You will need to either use lower Gradle plugin version or use Android
> Studio IDE to develop this project until IntelliJ IDEA merges latest
> updates of Android plugin from the Android Studio IDE.
>
> The classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1' should work fine
> in 2021.2 IntelliJ IDEA.

[(source)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405168877202-This-version-of-the-Android-Support-plugin-for-IntelliJ-IDEA-or-Android-Studio-cannot-open-this-project-please-retry-with-version-2020-3-1-or-newer-)