# Android studio : release FAILED _Could not find lint-gradle-27.0.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.0.2)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I tried to create a release   for  my projects but got the following error :

Could not find lint-gradle-27.0.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.0.2).

I used the following methods but it was useless.
[Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972122/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle-android-studio-3)

build.gradle :

repositories {

```
    google()
    jcenter()
   
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

    
}
```

gradle_version : 6.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you have mentioned that you have checked that stackoverflow page([Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle Android Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972122/could-not-find-com-android-tools-lintlint-gradle-android-studio-3)), but I had the same problem and this is what helped me:
visit the page that I have mentioned in the parentheses and search for @Saeed Arianmansh answer to the topic.