# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception : Flutter Gradle build failure

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

a while ago i deleted my .android folder in my flutter project and now i'm facing this error with the attached stack trace in Debog consule of my VsCode

here is the error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find lint-model-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/30.1.2/lint-model-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find repository-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.1.2/repository-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/7.1.2/gradle-api-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.1.2/builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/30.1.2/ddmlib-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/7.1.2/aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.2-7984345).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.1.2-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar
   > Could not find crash-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/30.1.2/crash-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find tracker-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/30.1.2/tracker-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find shared-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/30.1.2/shared-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/7.1.2/databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/7.1.2/databinding-common-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/7.1.2/baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/30.1.2/layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.1.2/builder-model-7.1.2.jar
   > Could not find dvlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/30.1.2/dvlib-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find common-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/30.1.2/common-30.1.2.jar
   > Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried updating my Gradle to the latest version as well as my Java.

re-initiated a fresh project and tried to launch the default flutter application but no difference.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please take look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127602/14388778. Also why would you delete .android folder from the project? Is it a desktop app? iOS only? If it's for android I'd suggest making a new project and moving lib files with pubspec to the new project. You could try `flutter clean` and `flutter create android` but I doubt it'll help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you should change build.gradle to
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
and do sync with gradle
and its work for me.
tell me if this fix you problem.